# I want to use OpenCV on Julia via PyCall

Tags: python, opencv, julia, pycall

I want to use OpenCV on Julia, then I tried to use PyCall.
I made my Python environment by pyenv, therefore, I tried below commands;

```
julia> ENV["PYTHON"] = "/Users/MYNAME/.pyenv/shims/python"
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("PyCall")
```

Then, I tried a below command and this error message was returned.

```
julia> using PyCall
ImportError: No module named site
```

This error message is too short to infer causes.
Anyone knows the causes and how to solve?

Comment: what about using official bindings? https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/da4/tutorial_julia.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyCall` is tested with Anaconda and it works best with the Anaconda installation inbuilt into Julia.

```
using Pkg
#ENV["PYTHON"] = ""
pkg"add PyCall"
#pkg"build PyCall"   #required to restore the default config if you changed it
pkg"add Conda"
using Conda
Conda.runconda(`install -c conda-forge opencv`)
using PyCall
const cv = pyimport("cv2")
```

Now you are ready to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

There are also Julia bindings for OpenCV, although they haven't been integrated with Julia's artifact system and so still require a certain amount of manual effort to install. To get started, see [this blog post](https://archit.me/blog/gsocfinal).